# Binary Power Error

Tags: java

Given integers n and k, find the value of n^k. I tried to do this recursively but I cant understand where I am going wrong. Can someone please help?

```
  int binaryPower(int n, int k) {

     if (k == 0) {
       return 1;
     }
     if (k % 2 == 0) {
       return binaryPower(n * n, k / 2);
         }
     return binaryPower(n, k - 1);
     }
```

Comment: Try your code with very simple inputs: `binaryPower(2, 0) == 1` (correct); `binaryPower(2, 1) == 1` (incorrect). Trace the execution with a pen and paper.

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in the case when `n % 2 != 0`. Here, you have to return `binaryPower(n, k - 1) * n;` but you return `binaryPower(n, k - 1);`.

Currently, if we take the example of 3<sup>3</sup>.
3<sup>3</sup> -> 3<sup>2</sup> -> 9<sup>1</sup> -> 9<sup>0</sup> -> 1

It should be:
3<sup>3</sup> -> 3<sup>2</sup> * 3-> 9<sup>1</sup> *3 -> 9<sup>0</sup> * 3 * 9-> 27

Changed Code:

```
int binaryPower(int n, int k) {

     if (k == 0) {
         return 1;
     }

     if (k % 2 == 0) {
         return binaryPower(n * n, k / 2);
     }

     return binaryPower(n, k - 1) * n;  // Changed
 }
```

Comment: Thank you; Wow I am dumb for not seeing that